# How can I perform a full system backup of my Truecrypted XP machine to a Truecrypted destination?

Tags: windows-xp, truecrypt

I suppose I'm looking for a method or tool that can create a full system/bare metal backup from within XP. It may also be possible for me to use a non-Truecrypted destination, but this would not be ideal. The possibility exists of mounting the Truecrypted backup disk to another PC and share it over a network, if there's a method that supports network drives. Beyond that, would there be any disadvantages of making a raw disk image, versus using a "proper" backup tool?

Comment: If you perform the backup from within Windows the backup will not be encrypted by Truecrypt, it'll be like any other backup. You can use which ever XP compatible backup tool you'd like.

Comment: Truecrypt is an obsolete and unsupported product.  You should consider switching to something else.

Answer (score 0):

First like mdpc said if security or privacy is really an issue, and your not just using truecrypt to keep your kids from logging into your computer and your seriously concerned about data privacy for business or whatever, you should consider finding a different tool. (maybe [DiskCrypter](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page) or [VeraCrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/veracrypt/) both free and very similar) To help you decide this think if there is anybody out there that either might be willing to pay someone to steal your data, or knows enough to do it themselves and has access to it, and if you can think of anyone, or have doubts, then find different tool.  Or if your like me you just do it because your paranoid and if someone really wants your data they at least have to work hard for it. ( oh no.. the NSA )

But on the other hand, is it really worth the hassle?

Concerning your "Raw backup", it depends on how you have truecrypt setup. If you have encrypted your entire drive and you were to try to back up the disk bit by bit (raw) your backup file would be the size of your whole drive, so if your HDD is 500gb your backup would be 500gb. Also if you set it up so you have to type your password in before windows will boot, then this method **will not work**. If this is the case leave a comment saying so and I will update my Answer.

As for what you could do. Have you looked at creating an encrypted container? I haven't used truecrypt for a while, but when I had It your could create an encrypted file container anywhere you wanted(i think this includes network drives) I don't remember if there was an option to dynamically allocate space to them, or if the size must be specified on creation, but either way, this could work for you.  Anyway they work just like an encrypted drive, once you create one you mount it with truecrypt and it will appear as virtual HDD(I think you can also set it up to just open like a folder) on your system.  The only downside is that if you can't create one that dynamically allocates its own space (like a virtual HDD for Virtual Box) then you would either have to know how big your backup would be or estimate high. Once this is done you just use windows backup or whatever other utility you want and use this virtual drive/folder for the save location.

When not mounted encrypted file containers look like and are just another file on your computer.

Another easy possibility would be to create a backup with a utility that supports encryption. or maybe just use 7zip to encrypt it after you make it.

Hope this helps :-)